# In C#, Remove Blank lines only at end of multiline string

Tags: c#

I have a multiline string that looks something like this:

```cs
string line = "one two three.    \r\n\r\n     ## ENDr\n\r\n "
```

I was thinking I could keep all the blank lines before #END and remove the blank lines at the end of the string using this expression:

```
string text2 = Regex.Replace(line, @"(\s*\r\n)+$", "");
```

However, it leads to an infinite loop on the Regex.Replace for some reason when i load a similar file into string line...

Any Ideas?

Comment: why not `.TrimEnd()`?

Comment: It works with multiline strings?

Comment: @Bimo: Did you test it before asking? A multiline string is still just a sequence of characters...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=net-6.0) to remove all whitespace characters from the end of a string. Since newlines are considered whitespace, this will chop them off. Any whitespace in the middle will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
string text2 = Regex.Replace(text, @"[\s\n\r]+$", "");
text2 += "\r\n";
```

Comment: Way too complicated. Just use `text.TrimEnd()` which will remove all whitespace from the end of a string.

Comment: `\s` already includes: `\n` - newline; `\r` - carriage return; `\t` - tab.

Answer (score -1):

`string.TrimEnd()` is your best bet. New lines and whatnot are characters as far as the string type is concerned, so TrimEnd() will only cull whitespace after the final character